# How to remove folders with a certain name

Tags: linux, unix, rm

In Linux, how do I remove folders with a certain name which are nested deep in a folder hierarchy?

The following paths are under a folder and I would like to remove all folders named `a`.

```
1/2/3/a
1/2/3/b
10/20/30/a
10/20/30/b
100/200/300/a
100/200/300/b
```

What Linux command should I use from the parent folder?

Comment: Perhaps missing the point but maybe it does assist someone: I have 410 folders in a main folder - each of the 410 with two sub-folders. All first sub-folders are named 'final' and contains edited pdfs and a Word content list. All the second sub-folders named tif_pdf_various_names contains originally scanned saved-to tiff files (some up to 200 pages), their un-edited pdfs and a draft .docx content list - thus a home work collection. I needed to make a collection of the 410 folders containing only the finally edited material - with the tiffs close to 4TB. Easiest method found was to use (in Micr

Answer (score 279, accepted):

If the target directory is empty, use find, filter with only directories, filter by name, execute rmdir:

```
find . -type d -name a -exec rmdir {} \;
```

If you want to recursively delete its contents, replace `-exec rmdir {} \;` with `-delete` or `-prune -exec rm -rf {} \;`. Other answers include details about these versions, credit them too.

Comment: Could you please explain what `{} \;` does?

Comment: `{}` can be read as "for each matching file/ folder" - i.e. it substitutes for each "found" file/ folder. `\;` is a terminator for the `-exec` clause.

Comment: This gives me a "cannot delete" error when the directory is not empty

Comment: Consider adding `-prune` flag to the answer as per @David Grayson suggestion. Without this, `find` will still try to visit the now missing folder and will eventually exit with an error code, which can e.g. fail a Docker build.

Answer (score 257):

Use find for name "a" and execute rm to remove those named according to your wishes, as follows:

```
find . -name a -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Test it first using ls to list:

```
find . -name a -exec ls {} \;
```

To ensure this only removes directories and not plain files, use the "-type d" arg (as suggested in the comments):

```
find . -name a -type d -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

The "{}" is a substitution for each file "a" found - the exec command is executed against each by substitution.

Comment: You probably want to add a "-type d" in there just incase a file matches the same name.

Comment: Also note that this will catch something like `1/2/a/3/4`, which may not be intended, so +1 for the recommendation to test first...

Comment: reco `echo {}` to test it first, instead of `ls {}`

Comment: Here go my `node_modules/`.

Comment: I used `find . -name a -type d -exec rm -rf {} \;` and it worked, although it printed out `find: ‘./subdir/subdir/a’: No such file or directory` for each directory deleted.

Comment: The 'No such file or directory' error comes from find because it tries to continue finding in that same folder you just removed. Use -prune to prevent that and shut it up.

Answer (score 117):

This also works - it will remove all the folders called "a" and their contents:

```
rm -rf `find . -type d -name a`
```

Comment: @Buffalo, how come? This defo works but so do the others. Would be surprised to find an env where this works but the others don't given all answers are essentially `find/rm`.

Comment: @wmorrison365 because if you do `find . -name a -exec rm -rf {} \;`, find will crash when it tries to enter that directory to look for more items, giving you an error like `find: '1/2/3/a': No such file or directory`.

Comment: @Alex Grönholm sure, but all folders named 'a' are nevertheless deleted. As you state, find can't subsequently look inside a deleted 'a' folder but that doesn't matter. Wanting to keep content of 'a' for subsequent processing before delete is a different use-case to what the OP asked.

Comment: @wmorrison365 Yes, the directories are deleted but I don't think it's good to recommend a solution where the command fails (returns a nonzero exit code).

Comment: This was giving me an error `illegal option --t`. I had to also pass the directory to search in (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25840713/illegal-option-error-when-using-find-on-macos): `rm -rf \`find . -type d -name a\``.

Comment: I need to add a `.` --> `rm -rf \`find . -type d -name a\``

Answer (score 68):

I ended up here looking to delete my `node_modules` folders before doing a backup of my work in progress using `rsync`. A key requirements is that the `node_modules` folder can be nested, so you need the `-prune` option.

First I ran this to visually verify the folders to be deleted:

```
find . -type d -name node_modules -prune
```

Then I ran this to delete them all:

```
find . -type d -name node_modules -prune -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Thanks to pistache

Comment: Ahh that worked nicely, to make this something you could use with ease you could save this as a little shellscript:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

echo "Found node_modules: ";

find -type d -name node_modules -prune;

read -r -p "Do you really want to delete all directories? [yes/no] " input;

if [ ! $input != "yes" ];
then
 find -type d -name node_modules -prune -exec rm -rf {} \;;
fi
```

Comment: On my Macbook Pro, when I ran your command, I got "illegal option -- t". So I added a dot. My command: `find . -type d -name node_modules -prune -exec rm -rf {} \;`

Comment: And this is why I'm switching to `pnpm` just cleared over 150gb on my computer. Thanks for this one.

Answer (score 38):

To delete all directories with the name `foo`, run:

```
find -type d -name foo -a -prune -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

The other answers are missing an important thing: the `-prune` option.  Without `-prune`, GNU find will delete the directory with the matching name and then try to recurse into it to find more directories that match.  The `-prune` option tells it to not recurse into a directory that matched the conditions.

Answer (score 23):

This command works for me. It does its work recursively

```
find . -name "node_modules" -type d -prune -exec rm -rf '{}' +
```

. - current folder

"node_modules" - folder name

Comment: exactly what I was looking for -- thanks!

Answer (score 16):

```
find ./ -name "FOLDERNAME" | xargs rm -Rf
```

Should do the trick.  WARNING, if you accidentally pump a `.` or `/` into `xargs rm -Rf` your entire computer will be deleted without an option to get it back, requiring an OS reinstall.

Comment: Oh, just that teeny tiny risk. Is that all? Haha. Super thanks for the warning. I definitely would make that typing mistake.

Comment: I like the `xargs` approach because it's easy to understand and easy to dry-run. You can solve the 'WARNING' issue by using `-print0` and '-0' (as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30135486/86967)). For example: `find -type d -iname ".recycle" -print0 |xargs -0 -n1 rm -rf`

Answer (score 16):

Combining multiple answers, here's a command that works on both Linux and MacOS

```
rm -rf $(find . -type d -name __pycache__)
```

Comment: Only one that worked for me that didnt also throw errors

Answer (score 13):

I had more than 100 files like

```
log-12
log-123
log-34
....
```

above answers did not work for me

but the following command helped me.

```
find . -name "log-*" -exec rm  -rf {} \;
```

i gave `-type` as `.` so it deletes both files and folders which starts with `log-`

and `rm -rf` deletes folders recursively even it has files.

if you want folders alone

```
find -type d -name "log-*" -exec rm  -rf {} \;
```

files alone

```
find -type f -name "log-*" -exec rm  -rf {} \;
```

Answer (score 7):

Another one:

```
"-exec rm -rf {} \;" can be replaced by "-delete"

find -type d -name __pycache__ -delete      # GNU find
find . -type d -name __pycache__ -delete    # POSIX find (e.g. Mac OS X)
```

Comment: This answer only works for empty folders. `-delete` does not remove non-empty folders.

Answer (score 4):

Earlier comments didn't work for me since I was looking for an expression within the folder name in some folder within the structure

The following works for a folder in a structure like:

b/d/ab/cd/file or c/d/e/f/a/f/file

To check before using rm-rf

```
find . -name *a* -type d -exec realpath {} \;
```

Removing folders including content recursively

```
find . -name *a* -type d -exec rm  -rf {} \;
```

Answer (score -2):

find path/to/the/folders -maxdepth 1 -name "my_*" -type d -delete