# "Illegal option" error when using find on macOS

Tags: macos, bash, shell, unix, find

I am trying to list the files only with the letter "R" at the end. I used `find` as follows in macOS Terminal,

```
find -type f -name '*R'
```

But I got the message saying `illegal option --t`.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

The first argument to `find` is the path where it should start looking.  The path `.` means the current directory.

```
find . -type f -name '*R'
```

You must provide at least one path, but you can actually provide as many as you want:

```
find ~/Documents ~/Library -type f -name '*R'
```

Comment: You should probably specify that you're talking about `bsd find`. `find -type f -name '*R'` is completely fine in `gnu`.

Comment: I'm talking about [standard POSIX `find`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html).

Comment: Yes, but the reason for the confusion here is likely that `gnu find` will default to `.` if you don't provide an argument. Mac OS uses `bsd` by default, which requires an argument if you don't provide one to `-f`. And using statements like `must provide at least one path` without specifying a version of `find` is likely just going to cause more confusion.

Comment: I came to this question, having the exact same confusion that @BroSlow was suggesting.