# Redirecting stdout with find -exec

Tags: linux, shell, find

I would like to merge all the files under a folder and its subfolders into a file `total.txt`, so I try

`find . -type f -exec cat {} +; > total.txt`

and the output can't be redirected

pipe can't work either:

`find . -type f -exec cat {} + | cat > total.txt`

It maybe caused by `-exec` which takes all the arguments after it as the command?

Is it right? And how to fix it? Or is there a better way to achieve this.

Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: I find that your second method works reasonably well.  What problem do you see with it?

Comment: @nobar   it run for a long time and seems never ends

Comment: I bet that was because it was copying total.txt into itself.  This didn't happen when I tested with small files, but it did happen once I had enough content in the folder -- it would probably keep reading and writing the growing total.txt until it filled up the disk.  This is why William suggested copying to `..` and I suggested using `! -path ./total.txt`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple way...

```
## WARNING: this only works for simple cases...
cat $(find ! -path ./total.txt -type f ) >total.txt
```

Here's another way, which is more robust to various special cases, such as spaces in file names or a very large number of files...

```
find ! -path ./total.txt -type f -print0 |xargs -0 cat >total.txt
```

Comment: By the way, `! -path ./total.txt` is only necessary based on the assumption that you want to write the file into the same directory that you are scanning.

Comment: thank you, it works! could you please give a short explanation of `$` 's usage

Comment: @simon_xia: It is [command substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) -- the output of the command replaces the command on the command-line.  For example `cat $(ls *.txt)` might become `cat file1.txt file2.txt`.

Comment: Why show the buggy form at all when you have the correct one?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: It's useful to point out the limitations of the simpler approach.

Comment: I get where you're coming from, but also wary of folks skimming an answer and grabbing the first code snippet they see.

Comment: Would you consider putting a comment directly above the first approach, ie. `## DON'T USE THIS; SEE BELOW`?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few issues.  The semi colon is terminating the command, so you are running two commands, with the second being an empty redirect.  Secondly, you need to prevent find from finding the file it is writing to, and an easy way to do that is to move it up a directory:

```
 find . -type f -exec cat {} + > ../total.txt
```