# Delete content of all folders with certain name

Tags: linux, command-line, rm

How can I delete content of all directories with a certain name?

I have a directory structure with many `build` directories inside. I want remove their content (all files and sub-directories), but leave the directory itself (so there will be empty `build` directory).

I was trying adapt solution proposed in this question: [How to remove folders with a certain name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13032701/how-to-remove-folders-with-a-certain-name) however after executing this command:

```
find . -name "build" -type d -exec rm -r "{}/*" \;
```

I got a responses (for each found match)

```
rm: cannot remove './path/to/found/build/*': No such file or directory
```

When I call directly

```
rm -r ./path/to/found/build/*
```

All files inside are removed (as expected)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the `*` in `-exec rm -r "{}/*"` expanded you would need to run a shell instead of executing `rm` directly, but with this option you must be careful not to introduce a command injection vulnerability. (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/156010/330217)

Another option is to use `-path` instead of `-name`

```
find . -path '*/build/*' -exec rm -r "{}" \; -prune
```

Option `-prune` is to avoid descending into a directory that has been removed before.